# Reverse for 'webapp.views.single_post' not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^new$', 'webapp.views.new_post', name="new_post"),
    url(r'^$', 'webapp.views.all_posts', name="main"),
    url(r'^post/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/$', 'webapp.views.single_post', name="single_post"),
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And a template that looks like this:

```
{% for i in posts %}
    <h3><a href={% url 'single_post' i.created_at.year i.created_at.month i.created_at.day %}>{{i.title}}</a></h3>
    Posted at: {{i.created_at}}
    <br>
    <br>
    {{i.text}}
    <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

But I keep getting a `NoReverseMatch` exception saying `Reverse for 'single_post' with arguments '(2012, 9, 30)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

**Edit**: I'm using Django 1.4.1 on Python 2.7

Comment: You are using the new url syntax. If you're using Django 1.3 or 1.4, make sure that you are including [`{% load url from future %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi) in your template.

Comment: @Alasdair did that, still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python docs:

> {m} Specifies that exactly m copies of the previous RE should be matched; fewer matches cause the entire RE not to match. For example, a{6} will match exactly six 'a' characters, but not five.

So url pattern should be:

```
r'^post/(\d{4})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/$'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

the url def for single_post takes 3 args, but you're passing 4

so instead of

```
<h3><a href={% url 'single_post' i.created_at.year i.created_at.month i.created_at.day i.slug %}>{{i.title}}</a></h3>
```

you want maybe

```
<h3><a href={% url 'single_post' i.created_at.year i.created_at.month i.created_at.day %}>{{i.title}}</a></h3>
```

oh, but you probably want the slug at the end, in which case in your urls.py, change it to something like...

```
url(r'^post/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/([\w-]+)$', 'webapp.views.single_post', name="single_post")
```

Comment: looks like its calling {% url ... %} inside a for loop through the posts, maybe one of the passed arguments is None for some post?   heh

Comment: I don't know, but looks like the request isn't getting passed, the only arguments I see are the ones in the template. Maybe that's the problem?